# Capture Google Account used to access a Google site from within a GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google site that has a Google script UI that accesses a Google Spreadsheet.

I would like for the Google Script to access a different spreadsheet based on the Google account that was utilized to access the Google site.

Is this possible and if so can someone point in the right direction with some sample code?

Thanks,

JON

Answer (score 2):

not possible if outside of Google Apps Domain

Comment: That is a bummer and seems odd as I am the one giving access to the site and I can view their email in the source code of the site.  Am I missing something in the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more information on what it is you are trying to do? When a user accesses a script, you can capture the active user with: 
   `var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser()`

If you had the names of the users that you wanted to have access to your spreadsheet in your script, I do not see why you couldn't let them access that spreadsheet. You will have to give them permissions in the spreadsheet before hand or give them permission during their time using the script via `.setEditor(currentUser)` or `.setViewer(currentUser)` functions.

When you publish your script, you can have it run as the user accessing the script (active user) or as you (effective user). You can publish the script and set permissions for anyone to access it, someone in your domain or even an anonymous user.